# Parse Array_agg on all columns

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, java-8

I use PostgreSQL 10.6 on Ubuntu 10.6-1.pgdg18.04+1 with `Java-8`. I have two tables:

Table test

```
 Column |         Type         | 
--------+----------------------+
 id     | character varying(5) |
```

Table test2

```
 Column |         Type          | 
--------+-----------------------+---
 c1     | character varying(5)  |   
 c2     | character varying(10) |
 c3     | character varying(10) |
 c4     | character varying(10) |
```

I am trying to fetch result from two tables in one go by `JOIN`.

This is my query

```
SELECT t1.*, Array_agg(t2.*) AS ent
FROM test AS t1 LEFT JOIN
     test2 AS t2
     ON t1.id = t2.c1 GROUP BY t1.id;
```

gives result

```
 id |            ent            
----+---------------------------
 a  | {"(a,e,f,g)","(a,b,c,d)"}
```

After getting values ent column

```
Array arr = rs.getArray("ent");

Object objects = arr.getArray();
```

object contains

```
objects = ["(a,e,f,g)","(a,b,c,d)"]
```

Now how to parse the result and get values as individual values since it is Object type ?

Casting it to `ResultSet[]` gives `cannot be cast to [Ljava.sql.ResultSet`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see from your question, the `getArray` method returns an `Array` of Strings. Instead of casting the `Array` to `Object` you can cast the results to an Array of Strings.

Example code for casting:

```
String[] arr = (String[])rs.getArray("ent");
```

Once you have an array of Strings, you can use String functions in order to parse and extract the values. For example, if the the following code if executed on your example input:

```
String[] arr = (String[])rs.getArray("ent");
    for(String row : arr) {
        String[] letters = row.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",");
        for(String letter : letters) {
            System.out.println(letter);
        }
    }
```

The following result should be printed:

```
a
e
f
g
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 3):

After casting the array of objects to `String[]`, there is a fairly and straightforward approach using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
String[] arr = (String[]) rs.getArray("ent");

Arrays.stream(arr)                                             // array to Stream
      .map(string -> string.replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",")) // remove brackets and split
      .flatMap(Arrays::stream)                                 // flatten the array 
      .forEach(System.out::println);                           // print the letters out
```

If you want the newly parsed items to the new array `String[]`, use the [`Stream::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) with the generator to get a correct type of array:

```
String[] array = Arrays.stream(arr)
                       .map(string -> string.replaceAll("[()]", "").split(","))
                       .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                       .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));       // [a, e, f, g, a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: So there is no way other than string manipulation and then parsing?

Comment: Is there some way other than string manipulation and then parsing? Is it possible to convert it back to ResultSet so that values can be accessed by column name. I am trying to avoid this approach because table rows can contain special characters  so more sophisticated string functions will be required.

Answer (score 1):

To collect the results as `String[][]` for each row in the result set, you should perform the following :

```
Arrays.stream((String[])rs.getArray("ent"))
    .map(element -> element.replaceAll("[()]", ""))
    .map(element -> element.split(","))
    .toArray(String[][]::new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PgArray.getArray()](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgArray.html#getArray--) to avoid *any* string manipulation:

```
String[] entAsArray = (String[]) rs.getArray("ent").getArray();
List<String> entAsList = Arrays.stream(entAsArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```